# Not able to retrun access token in custom policy with local login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have written one custom policy in azure AD b2c and its working ok , Now i want to return the access token as well if some one login from social media account i am able to return access token but with local account login i am not sure what steps needs to follow , Can any one help me on this

login via social media: Claims like below works fine

{
"exp": 7676868,
"nbf": 6868712,
"ver": "1.0",
"iss": "xyxjhgjgjg/v2.0/",
"sub": "26cd4=jfh1-9e4f-4d74-a4bd-afjhhdfkj6",
"aud": "584nczac-f6ba-4d42-a051-859700f247cj,
"acr": "b2c_1a_signuporsigninwithphoneoremail",
"iat": 1622700jhj,
"auth_time": 1622700447,
"givenName": "mnmn",
"surname": "nbnbnb",
"name": "nbvnvnv",
"**idp_access_token**": "v117OqsDGUyPjPlqmjfRCZB7zrsWZBxfzhgj,mnn,lwIEuDVyvE3VsH4cuZAf",
"tid": "d302bdbnbvv-09e5-42bf-9006-6bjhgjg"
}

Answer (score 0):

When you login via a social idp, the user enters their credentials on the social idp page, and in return gets an access token which B2C can use to grab their information after consent.

There is not the case for local accounts, because when the user logs in using a local account, they enter their credentials on the B2C idp itself. The access token is what constitutes these entire claims you have shared.

So in essence, when using social idp, there are two access tokens, one related to B2C, which constitute the entire claims, and another related to the social idp, which you highlighted in your question.